# Music Data is not showing in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to make a music player in Android and but I can not retrieve and show music data while trying to get all media files.
Below are my codes

**Below is the Song Model Class**

```
package com.subhrajit.testmplayer;

import android.net.Uri;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class SongModel implements Serializable {
    String trackTitle;
    Uri uri;
    Uri artWork;
    double trackSize;
    double trackDuration;

    public SongModel(String trackTitle, Uri uri, Uri artWork, double trackSize, double trackDuration) {
        this.trackTitle = trackTitle;
        this.uri = uri;
        this.artWork = artWork;
        this.trackSize = trackSize;
        this.trackDuration = trackDuration;
    }

    public String getTrackTitle() {
        return trackTitle;
    }

    public void setTrackTitle(String trackTitle) {
        this.trackTitle = trackTitle;
    }

    public Uri getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public void setUri(Uri uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    public Uri getArtWork() {
        return artWork;
    }

    public void setArtWork(Uri artWork) {
        this.artWork = artWork;
    }

    public double getTrackSize() {
        return trackSize;
    }

    public void setTrackSize(double trackSize) {
        this.trackSize = trackSize;
    }

    public double getTrackDuration() {
        return trackDuration;
    }

    public void setTrackDuration(double trackDuration) {
        this.trackDuration = trackDuration;
    }
}
```

**Below is Song Adapter Class**

```
package com.subhrajit.testmplayer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

public class AllSongsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AllSongsAdapter.SongHolder> {

    ArrayList<SongModel> allSongs;
    Context context;

    public AllSongsAdapter(ArrayList<SongModel> allSongs, Context context) {
        this.allSongs = allSongs;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SongHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.all_songs_layout,parent,false);
        return new SongHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SongHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.songName.setText(allSongs.get(position).getTrackTitle());
        holder.songSize.setText(String.valueOf(allSongs.get(position).getTrackSize()));
        holder.songDuration.setText(String.valueOf(allSongs.get(position).getTrackDuration()));

        //AlbumArt Setting

        Uri artWorkURL= allSongs.get(position).getArtWork();
        if (artWorkURL!=null){
            holder.albumArt.setImageURI(artWorkURL);
        }else if (holder.albumArt.getDrawable()==null){
            holder.albumArt.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_albumart);
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v->{
            Toast.makeText(context,allSongs.get(position).getTrackTitle()+" clicked!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (allSongs.size());
    }

    public class SongHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView songName,songDuration,songSize;
        ImageView albumArt;

        public SongHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            songName=itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewTrackName);
            songDuration=itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewTrackDuration);
            songSize=itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewTrackSize);
            albumArt= itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgAlbumArt);
        }
    }
}
```

**This is MainActivity Class where i am loading all media files**

```
package com.subhrajit.testmplayer;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<SongModel> allSongs=new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    AllSongsAdapter songAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (!checkPermission()){
            askPermission();
        }

        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        fetchAllTracks();

    }

public void fetchAllTracks(){
        Uri mediaStoreURI;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
            mediaStoreURI= MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.Audio.Media.VOLUME_NAME);
        }else{
            mediaStoreURI=MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        }

        //Define Projection
        //String Projection List for DB Cursor
        String[] projection={
                MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID
        };
        //Defining Order
        String sortOrder=MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED+"Desc";
        //String selection=MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC+" !=0";
        //getting songs
        try(Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(mediaStoreURI,projection,null,null,sortOrder)){
            //Saving cursor indices into local variables
            int idColumn=cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            int nameColumn=cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
            int durationColumn=cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION);
            int sizeColumn=cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE);
            int albumIDColumn=cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID);

            //Clear the previous loads before loading new
            while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                //Get the values of a column for a audio filE
                long id=cursor.getLong(idColumn);
                String name=cursor.getString(nameColumn);
                double duration=cursor.getDouble(durationColumn);
                double size= cursor.getDouble(sizeColumn);
                long albumID=cursor.getLong(albumIDColumn);

                //Song URI
                Uri uri= ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,id);
                //Album ArtWork URI
                Uri albumArtWorkUri= ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart"),albumID);
                //Remove Extensions
                name=name.substring(0,name.lastIndexOf("."));
                SongModel song=new SongModel(name,uri,albumArtWorkUri,size,duration);
                this.allSongs.add(song);
            }
            //display songs
            showSongs(this.allSongs);

        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    private void showSongs(ArrayList<SongModel> allSongs) {
        if (allSongs.size()==0){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No songs",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        allSongs.clear();
        allSongs.addAll(allSongs);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        songAdapter=new AllSongsAdapter(allSongs,MainActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(songAdapter);
    }

    private boolean checkPermission(){
        int result= ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (result== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void askPermission(){
         //For Android 10 and below
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},100);
                    }
                //For SDK 30 and Above Android 11 and above
                }else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.R){
                    if (!Environment.isExternalStorageManager()){
                        try{
                            Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                            intent.addCategory("DEFAULT");
                            intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("Package Name: %s",getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
                            startActivityIfNeeded(intent,100);

                        }catch (Exception ex){
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_MANAGE_MEDIA);
                            startActivityIfNeeded(intent,100);
                        }
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

Now i am uploading Layouts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:layout_scrollEffect="compress"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/primary_color_variant"
    android:layout_margin="7dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="12dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="398dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="7dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgAlbumArt"
            android:layout_width="68dp"
            android:layout_height="62dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/default_albumart" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewTrackName"
            android:layout_width="282dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgAlbumArt"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Song Title"
            android:textColor="@color/cyan_text"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewTrackDuration"
            android:layout_width="148dp"
            android:layout_height="31dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/viewTrackName"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgAlbumArt"
            android:text="Song Duration"
            android:textColor="@color/cyan_text"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewTrackSize"
            android:layout_width="118dp"
            android:layout_height="31dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/viewTrackDuration"
            android:layout_below="@+id/viewTrackName"
            android:textColor="@color/cyan_text"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:text="Song Size" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Requesting you to please help me.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? *Facing difficulties* does not really tell us anything.

Comment: I can not retrieve music data

Comment: Can you please try calling `fetchAllTracks` from your parent Activity and printing out `allSongs`? If `allSongs` is empty then your problem is with using the ContentResolver, not the RecyclerView.

Comment: Hello @Shn_Android_Dev I am calling it from parent activity MainActivity only. I added one if statement also to check if the ArrayList is empty or null but it went outside the if statement

Comment: Hello @Shn_Android_Dev,you are correct. Toast is throwing song arraylist size 0. Could you please help me to use contentresolver to get song data please?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with cursor query. I changed it like below and it is working as expected

```
public ArrayList<Song>fetchAllSongs(Context context){

        ArrayList<Song>tempAudioList=new ArrayList<>();
        Uri uri=MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[]projection={
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST

        };
        Cursor cursor=context.getContentResolver().query(uri,projection,null,null,null);
        if (cursor !=null){
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                String album=cursor.getString(0);
                String title=cursor.getString(1);
                String duration=cursor.getString(2);
                String path=cursor.getString(3);
                String artist=cursor.getString(4);

                Log.e("PATH: "+path, "Album: "+album);

                Song song=new Song(path,title,artist,album,duration);
                tempAudioList.add(song);
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        return tempAudioList;
    }
```